# javascript how to modify the current response in service worker?

Tags: javascript, response, service-worker, fetch-api

I use service worker to modify the fetch response with below code,

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log('install');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Claiming control');
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("fetch event")
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
      if(response.url.match('.mp4')){
        console.log(event);
        response.arrayBuffer().then(
          buffer =>{
            let length = 100
            view = new Uint8Array(buffer,0,length)
            for(i=0,j=length - 1; i<j; i++,j--){
                view[i] = view[i] ^ view[j]
                view[j] = view[j] ^ view[i]
                view[i] = view[i] ^ view[j]
            }
          }
        )
      }
      return response.clone();
    })
  );
});
```

Whichi will lead to this warning and error,

> The FetchEvent for "" resulted in a network error response: the
> promise was rejected.

> sw.js:60 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'clone' on
> 'Response': Response body is already used
> at sw.js:60

---

If I put the `clone()` before `arrayBuffer()` like below,

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log('install');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Claiming control');
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("fetch event")
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
      if(response.url.match('.mp4')){
        console.log(event);
        responseCloned = response.clone();
        responseCloned.arrayBuffer().then(
          buffer =>{
            let length = 100
            view = new Uint8Array(buffer,0,length)
            for(i=0,j=length - 1; i<j; i++,j--){
                view[i] = view[i] ^ view[j]
                view[j] = view[j] ^ view[i]
                view[i] = view[i] ^ view[j]
            }
          }
        )
      }
      return responseCloned;
    })
  );
});
```

It will lead to below warning and error,

> The FetchEvent for "" resulted in a network error response: a
> Response whose "body" is locked cannot be used to respond to a
> request.

> GET http://localhost/web/357765_decrypted.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instantiating and returning a new [`Response()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) with the decrypted bytes:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.url.endsWith('.mp4') {
    event.respondWith(getDecryptedResponse(event.request))
  }
})

async function getDecryptedResponse(request) {
  const response = await fetch(request)
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(await response.arrayBuffer())

  return new Response(
    new Blob([ decryptMp4Bytes(bytes) ], { type: 'application/mp4' }),
    {
      headers: response.headers,  // possibly required for this case
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you'll want to clone that response as the first thing you do.

When you call `arrayBuffer()` on it, you can no longer clone it.

Comment: If I move it before the `arrayBuffer()`, it will lead to `The FetchEvent for "<URL>" resulted in a network error response: a Response whose "body" is locked cannot be used to respond to a request.`

Comment: @LF00 Yeah, the response itself can't be used as soon as you call `arrayBuffer()` on it because it's now been used.  Its state is "dirty".  Response objects flow, and can't be used for two different purposes because the read states could be different.  That's what the `clone()` is for.  I missed the detail before though where you want to modify the buffer data.  What you need to do is actually create a *new* Response object with your buffer, after you've done the modification.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response

Comment: @LF00 Also note that if you're not sending the original response anywhere else, you don't have to clone it.  Sorry for the confusion.  The main point is that you can only use that response in one place.  :-)